# Submit a form with a file using jQuery append

Tags: jquery

I've a form where I have a table with 3 columns for simplicity:

- column 1 contains input field name
- column 2 contains multiple input fields colors
- column 3 contains multiple input file fields

I've a button to add a new row to my table

Also in each column 2 I've a button to add a new input text referred to the row. (COLORS)

Also in each column 3 I've a button to add a new input file referred to the row. (FILES)

For example:

```
<form id="form" action="" method="post">

<table id="mytable">
  <tr>
    <td>Name: <input type="text" class="name"></td>
    <td>
       Colors
       <div class="wrapperColors">
         <input type="text" class="color">
       </div>
       <button type="button" class="btn-addColor">Add new color</button>
     </td>
    <td>
       Attachments
       <div class="wrapperAttach">
         <input type="file" class="attachment">
       </div>
       <button type="button" class="btn-addAttach">Add new file</button>
     </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button type="button" id="btn-addRow">Add new row</button>

<button type="button" id="btn-submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

To add a new text input color:

```
$(".btn-addColor").on("click", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).closest("td").find(".wrapperColor").append('<input type="text" class="color">');
});
```

To add a new file input:

```
$(".btn-addAttach").on("click", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).closest("td").find(".wrapperAttach").append('<input type="file" class="attachment">');
});
```

Now, so all input fields are added dynamically and i don't know the number of rows and for each row the number of files

I use this method to post my data:

```
 $("#btn-submit").on("click", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   var form = $('<form>', {
        'action': '',
        'method': 'POST',
        'target': ''
    });

    $("#mytable tr").each(function(index, element) {

       form.append($('<input>', {'name': 'mytable_rows['+index+'][Name]', 'value': $(this).find(".name").val(), 'type': 'hidden' }) );

        $(this).find(".color").each(function(indexColor, elementColor) {
             form.append($('<input>', {'name': 'mytable_rows['+index+'][Colors]['+indexColor+'][Color]', 'value': $(this).val(), 'type': 'hidden' }) );
        });

    });
                    
    form.appendTo( document.body );
                    
    form.submit();

 });
```

So on my destination page index.php I have this to retrieve data:

```
$array_rows = $_POST['mytable_rows'];
foreach ( $array_rows as $row ) {
    echo "NAME: " . $row['Name'];
    foreach ( $row['Colors'] as $color ) {
       echo "COLOR: " . $color['Color'];
    }
}
```

All this code is created to keep indexes of colors referred to each row. It work great but I don't understand how to apply same logic to my FILES input fields. Any suggest?

Comment: So what's the problem? You modify a form which then gets submitted. It's not relevant how many elements are in that form because the browser will know what to do with all of them.

Comment: @Andreas because $_FILES[] are submitted with ordered indexes.... and I don't know then the files related for each row.... maybe row 1 has 5 files....maybe 0.... maybe 500...... how to know it after submit?